# Loading my own device driver as builtin in Yocto on my own meta layer

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I wrote my own USB driver for hardware and I want to add this driver as builtin. I have seen this post where they create a recipe to set as module and not builtin.

http://wiki.kaeilos.com/index.php/Howto_build_a_kernel_module_out_of_the_kernel_tree

Can you please guys help me in creating a recipe to set the module as builtin.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have external modules built into Linux Kernel. So you need to place your driver into `drivers/usb/` (based on the hardware type it needs to be placed in `drivers/usb/host/` if it is host controller driver or `drivers/usb/dwc*` or `drivers/usb/gadget/udc` if it is gadget driver) of your Linux Kernel tree.

Then you need to add according configuration in `Kconfig` and `Makefile` in `drivers/usb`. Finally you need to enable this as build in driver in defconfig/.config for building.

In short,

1. Place your driver in `drivers/usb`
2. Add `Kconfig` and `Makefile`. For example, `CONFIG_USB_HW_HCD`
3. Add to defconfig as `CONFIG_USB_HW_HCD=y`. In Yocto you can specify the defconfig file as `file://defconfig` in your `SRC_URI`.

**EDIT:**
As you are using meta-intel directly, you can create patch and bbappend to it. To do it,

1. git clone "intel kernel repo"
2. Add driver as mentioned above. Copy to `drivers/usb`, add `Kconfig, Makefile` entry.
3. Add this driver to git repo using `git add` + `git commit`
4. Create patch using `git format-patch`
5. Create a `.bbappend` file and add this patch. You can place this `.bbappend` file in any of your custom layer or in meta-intel itself.
6. Add defconfig fragment also into the `.bbappend` file for your Linux Kernel.

This way you don't need to have separate repo of same Linux Kernel.

Comment: Is this manual process. Manually running cp command.. Do we need to write any recipe for it.

Comment: You don't need to create new recipe. You must be having kernel compilation recipe from the meta-bsp layer. For example, meta-bbb for beaglebone black uses https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-bbb/blob/sumo/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stable_4.18.bb#L24 defconfig from https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-bbb/blob/sumo/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stable-4.18/beaglebone/defconfig.

Comment: I have this driver source code in my meta-layer, and I want this to be copied to linux-intel source code...

Comment: Yes, you need to copy the driver alone into drivers/usb of your Linux Kernel Source tree. Then add Kconfig and Makefile entry. Then add this entry to your defconfig/.config

Comment: @md.jamal: Am not sure what you meant by manual copy. You need your driver part of Kernel, so place inside kernel tree. That's the only option. If you want the driver as module, you can place as external build module or build from kernel source.

Comment: I am using meta-intel linux source code.. How do you want me to place my driver in the linux source code , which is fetched from the git tree.. Do you want me to have a separate git repository for my linux intel source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180425/discussion-between-parthiban-and-md-jamal).

Answer (score 0):

I hope your initial module will have module_init() and module_exit calls.

To make this usb module to be part of builtin kernel, very first thing is to modify you source code to remove module_init or module_exit calls add platform calls probe, init, etc./

Copy your source file to appropriate source directory like "driver/usb/*"

Add a entry in KCONFIG file with some description of that driver and also add rules for its dependencies

Add entry in Makefile for conditional compilation.

Configure your kernel using make menuconfig to enable your config tag and build your kernel

Comment: Initial part of your answer is wrong! So do you mean `module_init` and `module_exit` meant for building as loadable modules? This is not the case. Adding to it, platform driver can also be build as loadable modules.

Comment: @Parthiban thanks for info, I understood that while configuring kernel we can select a driver to be dynamic loadable or builtin driver, in this context I thought the driver might be having module_init/module_exit calls, anyway thanks for commenting